# Print the next three items in a list

Tags: python, list

I'm having a problem with python. 
First i want to store the Output of my for - loop in a new variable. 
Second i want to give out only the first three times (20:00, 21:00, 22:00)

Can somebody help me with this?

INPUT:

```py
import datetime
import time


list = ["18:00","19:00", "20:00", "21:00", "22:00", "23:00"]

lol = time.strftime("%H:%M")


for i in list:
    if i > lol:
        print(i)
```

OUTPUT:

```
20:00
21:00
22:00
23:00
```

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
new_variable = [time for time in list if time > lol][:3]
```

Comment: Thank you so much!!

Answer (score 0):

If you want to keep a for loop, you can add a simple counter:

```py
import datetime
import time


list = ["18:00","19:00", "20:00", "21:00", "22:00", "23:00"]

lol = time.strftime("%H:%M")

counter = 0

for i in list:
    if i > lol and counter < 3:
        print(i)
        counter += 1
```

Another option would be to use a list comprehension and to select the first three values from the list.

```py
values = [i for i in list if i > lol][:3]
```

Comment: Thank you my guy! have a nice day!

Answer (score 0):

I'm laying this out so it is easier for you to follow.
When one is new to python, things like list comprehension behavior can be... opaque.

btw, I'm a fan of extra print statements so I can see what the code is doing.
Just comment them out when you don't need them any more.

There are certainly more compact ways to do this, @[Robert Hamilton]'s answer is a great example.

```
import datetime
import time

list = ["18:00","19:00", "20:00", "21:00", "22:00", "23:00"]
lol = time.strftime("%H:%M")
my_new_list = [ ] # here is your new variable, we'll start empty

for i in list:
    print('checking i={}, my_new_list={}'.format(i, my_new_list))
    if i > lol:
        if len(my_new_list) < 3:
            my_new_list.append(i)
            print('keeping i={} since i > lol, now my_new_list={}'.format(i, my_new_list))
        else:
            print('ignoring i={}, already have enough.').format(i))
    else:
        print('skipping i={}, since i <= lol={}'.format(i, lol))
```

With a somewhat more efficient loop body (we break the loop after finding 3 things):

```
for i in list:
    if i <= lol:
        continue # keep looking
    # if we reach this point then i > lol.
    print('keeping i={}'.format(i)
    my_new_list.append(i)
    if len(my_new_list) >= 3:
        break
```

Comment: Thanks for your nice answer! I wish you a pleasant evening!